# jQuery append with css removes backslashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sprite

I am trying for hours to fix this problem and I am in a kind of deadend.

I have this chunk of code to generate a thumb image from a spritemap, parsing a json :

```
$('#dataArea').html(' ');
        for (var i in data.area) {
                    $('#dataArea').append(data.area[i].name +'<div class="img" style="height:48px; width:48px; background: url("//ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn4.15.1/img/sprite/'+data.area[i].image.sprite +') -'+data.area[i].image.x+'px -'+data.area[i].image.w+'px no-repeat;</div>')
               }
```

(variable names are just for demostration)

What I get as a result is e.g

```
<div class="img" style="height:48px; width:48px; background: url(" ddragon.leagueoflegends.com="" cdn4.15.1="" img="" sprite="" champion3.png)="" -384px="" -48px="" no-repeat;<="" div=""></div>
```

I lose the backslashes / and obviously I am doing something wrong with "" and ''.

If there is a more "elegant" way to do this feel free to show it

Expected result with vars:

```
<div class="img" style="height:48px; width:48px; background: url("//ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn4.15.1/img/sprite/+data.freeWeekChampions[i].image.sprite+") -+data.freeWeekChampions[i].image.sprite.x+ px - +data.freeWeekChampions[i].image.sprite.x+px no-repeat;"</div>
```

Expected result in html:

```
<div class="img " style="height:48px; width:48px; background: url('//ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.15.1/img/sprite/champion0.png') -96px -0px no-repeat;"></div>
```

Comment: what you want to do?? can you post your code on fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  forgot a `"`:

```
$('#dataArea').html(' ');
            for (var i in data.area) {
                        $('#dataArea').append("" + data.area[i].name + "<div class=\"img \" style=\"height:48px; width:48px; background: url('//ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.15.1/img/sprite/" + data.area[i].image.sprite + ".png') -" + data.area[i].image.x + "px -" + data.area[i].image.w + "px no-repeat;\"></div>";)

                   }
```

Comment: i still get something like this: <div class="img" style="height:48px; width:48px; background: url(" ddragon.leagueoflegends.com="" cdn4.15.1="" img="" sprite="" champion3.png")="" -384px="" -48px="" no-repeat;<="" div=""></div>

Comment: Please gimme the expected result with vars in  { }

Comment: If i am not making something wrong i get and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. I added an expected result if that helps

Comment: I did some modifications e.g removed the .png and the last ";" because i got errors and it worked! A million thank you really!

Comment: @user3127632 you're welcome. And I thank coffeescript and fenced strings :)

Answer (score 2):

That line of code is so complicated. It will keep being a source of bugs!

It might be better to build the element you want to append in a more readable way

Something like

```
var element = $("<div />");
element.addClass("img");
element.css("background-image", "url('image-url')");
...
$dataArea.append(element);
```

The above is a lot more readable and easy to make changes.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to append an html entity not just html string, try this:

```
var child, area = $('#dataArea');
for (var i in data.area) {
    child = $('<div>');//<-- change as per your need
    child.html(data.area[i].name +'<div class="img" style="height:48px; width:48px; background: url("//ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn4.15.1/img/sprite/'+data.area[i].image.sprite +') -'+data.area[i].image.x+'px -'+data.area[i].image.w+'px no-repeat;</div>');
    area.append(child);
}
```

Comment: I get an Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class="img" style="height:48px; width:48px; background: url("//ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn4.15.1/img/sprite/champion3.png) -384px -48px no-repeat;</div>

Comment: i stil get my original result without backslashes :/